# Does the Spotfire API provides a CustomMenuGroup in the View menu?

Tags: tibco, spotfire

Spotfire provides creating a CustomMenuGroup in the Tools menu. Looks like that:

```
public sealed class CustomToolsAddIn : AddIn
{
    protected override void RegisterTools(ToolRegistrar registrar)
    {
        base.RegisterTools(registrar);

        CustomMenuGroup menuGroup = new CustomMenuGroup("My menu sub group");

        registrar.Register(new MyTool(), menuGroup);
    }

    ...
}
```

But instead of tools we are creating views and register it like that:

```
protected override void RegisterViews(ViewRegistrar registrar)
        {
            base.RegisterViews(registrar);
            registrar.Register(typeof(Control), typeof(CustomPanelModel), typeof(CustomPanelUI));
        }
```

This works fine but I am now wondering if it is possible to group our own views in a custom group menu in the views menu like it is possible in the tool menu.
Any idea?